# Swift - app crashes after setting UserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to implement a "always logged in" function in to my app. The problem is that if I restart my app, it crashes. This is what I did:

**set Userdefault:**

```
@objc func loginButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    let email = self.emailTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    let password = self.passwordTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    // start button animation
    loginButton.startAnimation()

    let qualityOfServiceClass = DispatchQoS.QoSClass.background
    let backgorundQueue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: qualityOfServiceClass)
    backgorundQueue.async {
        // check if account details correct
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (result, error) in

            if error != nil {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    // error -> stop animation
                    self.loginButton.stopAnimation(animationStyle: .shake, revertAfterDelay: 0) {
                        self.errorLabel.text = error!.localizedDescription
                        self.errorLabel.alpha = 1
                    }
                }
            }else {
                // correct acount details -> login
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "isLoggedIn")
                    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
                    // transition to home ViewController
                    self.transitionToHome()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**checking UserDefault:**

```
class MainNavigationControllerViewController: UINavigationController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if isLoggedIn() {
        let homeController = MainViewController()
        viewControllers = [homeController]
    }
}

fileprivate func isLoggedIn() -> Bool {
    return UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isLoggedIn")
}
```

}

The user logs in via Firebase and all the data is stored in Cloud Firestore.

**Error**

```
cell.customWishlistTapCallback = {

            let heroID = "wishlistImageIDX\(indexPath)"
            cell.theView.heroID = heroID

            let addButtonHeroID = "addWishButtonID"
            self.addButton.heroID = addButtonHeroID

            // track selected index
            self.currentWishListIDX = indexPath.item

            let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WishlistVC") as? WishlistViewController

            vc?.wishList = self.dataSourceArray[self.currentWishListIDX]
            // pass drop down options
            vc?.theDropDownOptions = self.dropDownButton.dropView.dropDownOptions
            vc?.theDropDownImageOptions = self.dropDownButton.dropView.dropDownListImages
            // pass current wishlist index
            vc?.currentWishListIDX = self.currentWishListIDX
            // pass the data array
            vc?.dataSourceArray = self.dataSourceArray
            // set Hero ID for transition
            vc?.wishlistImage.heroID = heroID
            vc?.addWishButton.heroID = addButtonHeroID
            // allow MainVC to recieve updated datasource array
            vc?.dismissWishDelegate = self

            vc?.theTableView.tableView.reloadData()
            self.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
```

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

at line:

> let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WishlistVC") as! WishlistViewController

I guess it is not as easy as I thought. Does anyone know why the app crashes and how I can solve this? :)

Comment: Add your crash logs.

Comment: which line cause the crash?

Comment: I updated my question. But I have no idea why that happens

Comment: if the error is in imagePreview.image assignation and it is an Unexpectedly found nil it doesn't seam that it has to do with UserDefaults.

Comment: Where is that line of code getting called? Put a breakpoint on that line and check if imagepreview is nil or not?

Comment: true. but why would it found nil there ? I mean I just set the `image` ?

Comment: the problem i guess will be that this image doesn't exists UIImage(named: "iconRoundedImage")

Comment: Because if iconRoundedImage is nil it will throw a  Unexpectedly found nil...

Comment: but it does. If I remove the `if-case` from `viewDidLoad` inside `MainNavigationController` everything works just fine

Comment: Well the reason why i say it can be nil is because you are doing always logged in,  and crash is happening after you restart. therefore it suggest you might be trying to set the image to imageview when it could be nil..

Comment: Try `imagePreview?.image = UIImage(‘imagename’)`

Comment: Is the crash occurring in `MainViewController`? Is `imagePreview` an `@IBOutlet`?  Because you are not instantiating the view controller from the storyboard, it's outlets will be `nil`

Comment: `imagePreview?` solved that problem but now i get another `found nil` error.. and yes, @Paulw11 the crash is occurring in `MainViewController`

Comment: I updated my question again. Thanks for all your help so far :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating your `MainViewController` instance using a simple initialiser (`MainViewController()`) rather than instantiating it from the storyboard.  As a result, any `@IBOutlet` properties will be `nil` since it is the the storyboard process that allocates those object instances and assigns them to the properties.

You need to add an identifier to your main view controller scene (if it doesn't already have one) and use that to instantiate the view controller instance.  E.g.  assuming the scene identifier is "MainScene" you would have something like:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if isLoggedIn() {
        let homeController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainScene") 
        viewControllers = [homeController]
    }
}
```

The crash in your updated question indicates that either the scene with the identifier `WishlistVC` doesn't have its class set to `WishlistViewController` or it isn't found so the forced downcast crashes.

Comment: thanks :) that solved my problem and the app is no longer crashing.